# How tow Storage Link on Cpanel in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

i have a shared hosting and i have some upload image, this image is uploaded and saved in folder files:

project

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
resources
routes
storage
-app
  -public
   -files (here)
framework
logs
vendor
```

i need to display this image to view, so i need move or linked **files** folder to **public_html**, i am trying with create symlink and put this to public_html like this but its unsolved

and run  **[www.domainme.com/symlinkcreate.php](http://www.domainme.com/symlinkcreate.php)**

```
<?php symlink('/home/domainme/project/storage/app/public/files', '/home/domainme/public_html/files/storage');?>
```

iam trying with add in **Route** -> **web.php**

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
Artisan::call('storage:link');});
```

and iam try with **[www.domainme.com/foo](http://www.domainme.com/foo)**

but its nothing happen. someone can help? i just need my image displayed. thank you very much